# Using Jenkins Blue Ocean to Deploy builds

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I've recently been setting up my own little CI/CD setup using Docker and Jenkins. I've installed the new Blue Ocean plugin for Jenkins and set up a pipeline that: Pulls from Git -> Runs tests -> Builds. Which works perfectly.

However, I've not been able to find out how to create an appropriate deploy/publish step in the pipeline. After the build, I want the Jenkins container to SSH onto my VPS that is running all the Docker containers, pull and then re-build that specific container (using Docker Compose).

I noticed within Blue Ocean there is the option to input a bash script that'll run after test/build - is this what I should be using?

I have been looking at using the Publish over SSH plugin for Jenkins but I have not been able to find whether this plugin works with Blue Ocean, nor have I been able to find out how to create ssh keys for the Jenkins container to be used.

I would greatly appreciate any insight/recommendations into how I should publish/build the updated containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `sh 'ssh...'` step should be enough to call a script on your VPS, which would (the script) handle all docker operations.

If your private ssh key is protected with a passphrase, you might want to wrap that call in an agent with the [pipeline steps "ssh-agent"](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/):

```
node {
  sshagent (credentials: ['deploy-dev']) {
    sh 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l cloudbees 192.168.1.106 uname -a'
  }
}
```

As [pmr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105672/pmr) comments, the [JENKINS SSH Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Credentials+Plugin) can be used to stored the ssh private key.
You can also read the recent article "[SSH Credentials Management with Jenkins](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/222838288-SSH-Credentials-Management-with-Jenkins)".

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer. But I'm still not sure how I would get ssh keys onto my jenkins image (as it's being run on Docker).

Comment: @HarveyD you can build your own jenkins image, with a Dockerfile adding (COPY) the ssh keys.

Comment: @HarveyD Use the credentials plugin and store them as a credential.

Comment: @pmr good point (included in the answer for more visibility.)

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it working! Yep, the solution was to use the "ssh-agent" plugin for Jenkins (works on the Jenkins Docker container!).

I did the following:

1. simply created a ssh keypair on my local machine (ssh-keygen)
2. copy pasted the id_rsa to the ssh-agent plugin
3. copied over the id_rsa.pub onto the machine I wanted to run the build/publish script on

My mistake was going straight to using BlueOcean without really understanding how builds work in Jenkins. BlueOcean doesn't allow for integration with ssh-agent. You must add:

```
sshagent (credentials: ['deploy-dev']) {
    sh 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l cloudbees 192.168.1.106 uname -a'
}
```

To the Jenkinsfile that your build is using.

I hope this helps everyone else that runs into the same problems.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed feedback, in addition to my answer. +1